# RewriteRule: trying to get rid of dashes

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite dashes in URL so that they don't exist internally. For example this URL

localhost/mysite/**about-me**

**"about-me"** should be rewritten to **"aboutme"**. I need this because the controller class name depends on this route string, and I obviously can't use dashes for this.

This is the condition and rule I found which I thought should fit my needs:

```
# Condition is to avoid rewrite on files within specified subdirs
RewriteCond $1 !^(css|img|ckeditor|scripts)
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-([^-]+)$ $1$2 [L]
```

However it seems that it's not working, since the controller class **Aboutme** is not instanciated. I get a **404 error** instead, and I don't have any problem with similar controller classes without a dash in their names.

Could you please give me a hand on this?

Comment: well, the entry filepath is **localhost/mysite/index.php**, but I'm already handling this in another pair condition-rule: **RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|css|img|scripts|ckeditor|robots.txt|sitemap.xml|sitemap.xml.gz) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]**

Comment: The `-` is a regexp condition if I rembember correctly, have you tried with `\-`

Comment: I've also tried escaping the dashes with `^([^\-]+)\-([^\-]+)$` and `^([^\-]+)-([^\-]+)$` and the problem persists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not go with routes?

```
$route['about-me'] = 'aboutme/index';
```

Comment: yes. It's an option I considered, but I was trying to do it with Apache. I should be able to do it. If I didn't get it, I would go for the Codeigniter routes.

Comment: I would definitely go with routes. Especially handy when things get dynamic, i.e. `$route['product/(:num)/([a-z]+)'] = 'product/view/$1/$2';`

Comment: I will take your advice and will use routes. Anyway it would be nicer if we could find out why my rewrite rule is not working.

Comment: I need to figure out how to do the same with mod_rewrite. I gave you points already. But I don't consider the question solved yet.

Comment: Just curious: why do you prefer .htaccess over CI routes? What advantage do you hope to obtain?

Comment: It's not a question about advantages now. I'm going to use the CI routes. However I'd like to get the other way solved just in case I bump into this problem again and I'm not relying on a framework like CI. Just to have more resources clear, or to fill all the gaps if you know what I mean. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try removing ^ and $

```
# Condition is to avoid rewrite on files within specified subdirs
RewriteCond $1 !^(css|img|ckeditor|scripts)
RewriteRule ([^-]+)-([^-]+) $1$2 [L]
```

Comment: Done, but I get the same problem.

Comment: RewriteRule ([^\-]+)\-([^\-]+) $1$2 [L]

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the Router class.
In */application/core* create a file called **MY_Router.php** (**MY** is the default prefix) and copy this into it;

```
<?php if (! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class MY_Router extends CI_Router {

    function set_class($class) {
        $this->class = str_replace('-', '_', $class);
    }

    function set_method($method) {
        $this->method = str_replace('-', '_', $method);
    }

    function _validate_request($segments) {
        // Does the requested controller exist in the root folder?
        if (file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.str_replace('-', '_', $segments[0]).'.php')) {
            return $segments;
        }
        // Is the controller in a sub-folder?
        if (is_dir(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$segments[0])) {       
            // Set the directory and remove it from the segment array
            $this->set_directory($segments[0]);
            $segments = array_slice($segments, 1);

            if (count($segments) > 0) {
                // Does the requested controller exist in the sub-folder?
                if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$this->fetch_directory().str_replace('-', '_', $segments[0]).'.php')) {
                    show_404($this->fetch_directory().$segments[0]);
                }
            } else {
                $this->set_class($this->default_controller);
                $this->set_method('index');

                // Does the default controller exist in the sub-folder?
                if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$this->fetch_directory().$this->default_controller.'.php')) {
                    $this->directory = '';
                    return array();
                }

            }

            return $segments;
        }

        // Can't find the requested controller...
        show_404($segments[0]);
    }
}
```

This will automatically rewrite - to _ for you.
If you don't want underscores change the code to replace them with nothing;
all occurences of `str_replace('-', '_',` to `str_replace('-', '',`

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use a regular expression in a route than overriding the Router class? Mudshark suggested me to use routes already. However it would be great if I could also figure it out how to do it in the Apache server, using mod_rewrite.

Comment: I have always used an extended router class. This way it doesn't make what platform the code gets deployed on, it is self-contained. I often have to do sites that go on IIS, so it saves messing around with web.config.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it with mod-rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/(.*)([\w]*)-([\w]*)(.*)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule  .* %1%2%3%4 [L,DPI]
```

Won't redirect but can do it adding `R=301` like this [R=301,DPI,L].

Does not have to be `about-me`. Can be any words pair at any position. i.e.

`localhost/mysite/about-me` = `.../aboutme` or

`localhost/mysite/folder1/folder2/folder3/my-folder` = `.../myfolder` or

`localhost/mysite/folder1/folder2/my-folder/folder3` =  `.../myfolder/...`

Comment: In my case I just want it to work only in the route segments, not in real subdirectories. Imagine this is what I'm using: `localhost/my-site/about-me`. **my-site** is a real directory to a local web of mine. I only want to remove dashes in the route segments like **about-me** because it's routed to a php controller class and it can't have any dash. What should you suggest?

Comment: I think it will work the same. My example assumes the folders don't exist, except the last one. I just tried to give more versatility to the algorithm. Give it a try.